# Why default constructor doesn't work for `vector::emplace_back`

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct PersonA {
  int age; std::string name;    
  PersonA(int _age, const std::string& _name) : age(_age), name(_name) {}
};

struct PersonB {
  int age; std::string name;    
  PersonB(int _age, const std::string&& _name): age(_age), name(_name) {}
};

struct PersonC {
  int age; std::string name;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<PersonA> personA;  
  personA.emplace_back(10, "nameA");   // fine

  std::vector<PersonB> personB;  
  personB.emplace_back(10, "nameB");   // fine

  std::vector<PersonC> personC;  
  //personC.emplace_back(10, "nameC"); // (the implicit move constructor) not viable
                                       // (the implicit default constructor) not viable

  personC.emplace_back();              // UPDATE: fine.
}
```

Question> Why does `vector::emplace_back` request explicit definition of constructor otherwise the following line doesn't work?

```
// why it cannot make use of the default constructor of PersonC?
personC.emplace_back(10, "nameC");
```

Also, `vector::emplace_back` doesn't support uniform intialization. Does this have sth to do with the above issue?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, the lack of `emplace_back`'s usage uniform initialization is the reason this is happening.

Comment: Beware of badness caused by using leading underscores...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::emplace_back()` takes the arguments you provide to it and perfect-forwards them to the constructor of the `value_type` object it is supposed to create (in your case, `PersonC`).

Table 101 of the C++11 Standard specifies the semantics of `emplace_back()`:

> *Expression*: `a.emplace_back(args)`
>
> *Return type*: `void`
>
> *Operational semantics:* Appends an object of type `T` **constructed with
> `std::forward<Args>(args)...`**.

There is no constructor of `PersonC` that accepts an `int` and a `const char*` (or anything which could be constructed from an `int` and a `const char*`, respectively), hence the error.

In case you're wondering, the only constructors that a compiler *can* implicitly define are the default constructor, the copy constructor, and the move constructor.

Comment: I think I got the issue I had. The compiler does provide a default constructor but it does NOT provide a constructor with two parameters!

Comment: @q0987: Right, such constructors are never implicitly generated

Comment: always know the rule and just get confused by myself:)

Comment: @q0987: Happens to everyone ;)

Comment: @Yakk: Right, std-proposals has been silent for a while... :D